# Triangle minimum path sum top down not bottom up

Tags: javascript

Trying to understand the `Triangle - Minimum path sum` solution in JavaScript.

The problem statement is as follows (https://leetcode.com/problems/triangle/):

> Given a triangle array, return the minimum path sum from top to bottom.

> For each step, you may move to an adjacent number of the row below. More formally, if you are on index i on the current row, you may move to either index i or index i + 1 on the next row.

> Example 1:

```
Input: triangle = [[2],[3,4],[6,5,7],[4,1,8,3]]
Output: 11
Explanation: The triangle looks like:
   2
  3 4
 6 5 7
4 1 8 3
The minimum path sum from top to bottom is 2 + 3 + 5 + 1 = 11 (underlined above).
```

There are many solutions around and I picked one from [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/triangle/discuss/342223/Clean-Javascript-4-Lines-Beats-98).

The issue is the solution concentrates on bottom-up calculation (why is that?) than top-down minimum path. Since the problem is "Start from the top and have to find the way to the bottom of the minimum path sum".

What I am trying to solve is a little different than the actual problem. I put the first row which represents the number of rows on the triangle. So starting row for the calculation will always be row[1].

```
   3 
   1 
  2 3 
 4 5 6
```

the solution was done like below:

```
function calculateLowestPath(triangle) {
 let firstRow = 1;
 let firstCol = 0;

  for (let row = triangle.length - 2; row > -1; row--) {
   for (let col = 0; col < triangle[row].length; col++) {
    triangle[row][col] += Math.min(triangle[row + 1][col],triangle[row + 1][col + 1]
  );
 }
}
 return triangle[firstRow][firstCol];
}
```

**Problem:** The above solution is for bottom up calculation. How can this be done top down?

Comment: just introduce a top down loop, and leave the inner loop as it is. 
Also your solution is quadratic complexity which is not how it should be done otpimaly.

Answer (score 0):

(newbie here) I believe the explanation of the algorithm provider is clear. The reason why from bottom to top is to increase the performance.
Algorithm from top also works. Generally for a number, just add its shoulder min number to itself and loop down. Then finially you will have a array of n(layer number) numbers. But you still need to find the minimum number of this array because you dont know which one is the smallest.